# Facebook open graph action not getting updated timestamp after update

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm using the PHP SDK for adding reviews/ratings of books.  Whenever someone updates the rating of a book or a review on my site, I am sending in an update request through the API for the original open graph id associated with the rating/review and it *does* update the rating/review values but the timestamp on the action is still set to whenever it was first submitted.  I want to have the time be reflected of the last update so it shows up in their activity feed/timeline in the right place.

I've tried modifying end_time,start_time and publish_time based on the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/

but nothing does anything to modify the timestamp of the action.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to delete the action and create a new one altogether.